# how to toggle dataTable specific column only when save button is click after the checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a dataTable and i want to visible and invisible a specific column of this table when i unchecked the checkbox. for example unchecked the " Name " checkbox and table " Name " column will get hide but what i want is it should only work when i click save button. can anyone help me to achieve that

```js
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //var for the datatable object
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "scrollY": "300px"
        });

        function filterGlobal() {
            $('#example').DataTable().search(
                $('#global_filter').val(),
                $('#global_regex').prop('checked'),
                $('#global_smart').prop('checked')
            ).draw();
        }

        function filterColumn(i) {
            $('#example').DataTable().column(i).search(
                $('#col' + i + '_filter').val(),
                $('#col' + i + '_regex').prop('checked'),
                $('#col' + i + '_smart').prop('checked')
            ).draw();
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //store the datatable object
            globDataTable = $('#example').DataTable();

            $('input.global_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
                filterGlobal();
            });

            $('input.column_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
                filterColumn($(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column'));
            });
        });

        // hide specific columns of a table
        var globDataTable;
        $(".nametoggleCheck").click(function (){
            var col = globDataTable.column(0);
            col.visible(!col.visible());
        })
        $(".positiontoggleCheck").click(function () {
            var col = globDataTable.column(1);
            col.visible(!col.visible());
        })
        $(".officetoggleCheck").click(function () {
            var col = globDataTable.column(2);
            col.visible(!col.visible());
        })
        $(".agetoggleCheck").click(function () {
            var col = globDataTable.column(3);
            col.visible(!col.visible());
        })
        $(".starttoggleCheck").click(function () {
            var col = globDataTable.column(4);
            col.visible(!col.visible());
        })
        $(".salarytoggleCheck").click(function () {
            var col = globDataTable.column(5);
            col.visible(!col.visible());
        })
    //var for the datatable object
    // hide specific columns of a table end
    </script>
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>
            <input class="nametoggleCheck" type="checkbox" name="foo" checked> Name</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="positiontoggleCheck" checked> Pisition</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="officetoggleCheck" checked> Office</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="agetoggleCheck" checked> Age</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="starttoggleCheck" checked> Start date</li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="salarytoggleCheck" checked> Salary</li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="my_button">
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <table id="example" class="display dataTableShow" border="1" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, You want the table column show - hide effect only when 'Save' button is clicked. Then instead of doing show -hide on checkbox click, do it only when the 'save' button is clicked like this-

```
       <script>

    //var for the datatable object
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "scrollY": "300px"
    });

    function filterGlobal() {
        $('#example').DataTable().search(
            $('#global_filter').val(),
            $('#global_regex').prop('checked'),
            $('#global_smart').prop('checked')
        ).draw();
    }

    function filterColumn(i) {
        $('#example').DataTable().column(i).search(
            $('#col' + i + '_filter').val(),
            $('#col' + i + '_regex').prop('checked'),
            $('#col' + i + '_smart').prop('checked')
        ).draw();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //store the datatable object
        var globDataTable = $('#example').DataTable();

        $("#my_button").click(function() {
            console.log("Save clicked");
            var i = 0;
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
               // sList += "(" + $(this).val() + "-" + (this.checked ? "checked" : "not checked") + ")";
               console.log(this.checked);
                var col = globDataTable.column(i);
                if(! this.checked) {
                    col.visible(false);
                }
                else {
                    col.visible(true);
                }

                i++;
            });

        });            

    });

        </script>
```